# Replacing a hyperlink with an image on excel

Tags: excel, image, hyperlink

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple hyperlinks, which link to pictures on the internet.  Is there a simple or easy way to replace the hyperlink with the actual image, other than copying and pasting the image from the internet individually for each link?

Comment: Assuming all your links are in a list you can just loop through the list using `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(cells(x,1).Select`.  You'll need to tweak the position too.